# C# object still exists after removing its reference

Tags: c#, reference, null

I'm just curious how this works:
In my class Form1.cs I have declared an object static:

```
 public static Class1 class1;
```

This is how the constructor of Class1 looks like:

```
  public Class1()
{
    Form1.class1 = null;
}
```

I expected to get a null reference exception in  MS VS 2010

```
 class1 = new Class1();
 class1.showMSG();
```

But instead it just executes showMSG() (showMSG is not static) like I've never set the reference to class1 to null.
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You assign a value to class1 before calling showMSG...

Comment: You will never get a null reference excp from this. Because you are creating object when you are using new keyword. This is the basic of the basic.

Comment: Rather if you want to produce a null reference exception then you might want to try using the class without the new key word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class1's constructor sets

```
Form1.class1 = null;
```

But when you execute

```
class1 = new Class1();
```

the assignment to `class1` (which is the same `class1`) happens *after* the constructor executes.  So `Form1.class1` now has a value.

Comment: @OP You need to think of `class1 = new Class1();` as several different operations, not one atomic operation.  First it creates the new instance of `Class1` with `new Class1()`, then it runs the constructor for that object (setting `class1` to `null`) then it assigns that newly created object to `class1`.  Once you break it down like this it's clear why arx's answer is correct.

Comment: @Servy but once class1 has a value, isnt that still just *null* ?

Comment: @JaneDoe No, it's not null, it's the newly created `Class1` object that is returned from `new Class1()`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you intialize it actually `class1 = new Class1();` here, according to the code provided.

You first set it to `null`

```
Form1.class1 = null;
```

after

```
  class1 = new Class1(); //INIT THE SAME (ACCORDING TO THE NAME) OBJECT
  class1.showMSG();      //CALL A METHOD ON IT.
```

**EDIT**

According to **edited** question:

```
public Class1()
{
    Form1.class1 = null;
}
```

doesn't reset anything as you're still *inside* a `constructor`, on exit from it actually object will be constructed and assigned to the same object you assigned `null` before.

Comment: Not true.  `class1` is set to null **before** `class1 = new Class1();` sets `class1` to be the newly created instance.

Comment: @Servy: and ? That new instance let's to OP to call actually an instance method on it.

Comment: You seem to not be addressing the tricky issue here.  In the constructor (called via `new Class1()` it is setting `Form1.class1` to null.  Basically the OP assumes that `class1 = new Class1();` will assign the instance to `class1` and then run the constructor (which sets the field to null) and so will result in a null pointer on the next line.  That logic is mistaken; those actions don't take place in the order he assumed.

Comment: @Servy: at the moment I add the answer question wasn't edited.

Comment: @Servy that was indeed the order I assumed but if that's incorrect then what order is correct? PS: I never edited the question's logic only the layout

Comment: @user1415067 See [The answer that I upvoted and endorsed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12590686/1159478) along with my comment in which I elaborate on what it asserts.

Comment: Yes thanks now it's clear to me. I always assumed the object is created after it's assignment; then executing the code in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's easiest to explain if you break up your last two lines, into:

```
var tmp = new Class1();  // makes class1 null
class1.showMSG();        // would raise exception, remove this line to proceed
class1 = tmp;            // class1 is no longer null
class1.showMSG();        // no exception, instance exists to call method on
```